# C++ enum data structure

Tags: c++, enums

Can someone give me a real time need for enum data structure. As in example in some real system where it can be used? And what is the reason for having such a data structure. The example given was

```
enum colors_t {black, blue, green, cyan, red, purple, yellow, white};
```

But i felt, this is similar to string array. I am trying to understand the notion with which this feature was added to C++. Thanks !

- Regards
  Sethu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, Bjarne Stroustrup talks about bringing `enum`s into C++ in the book *The Design and Exolution of C++* with the statement "C enumerations constitute a curiously half-baked concept.  Enumerations were not part of the original conception of C and were apparently reluctantly introduced into the language as a concession to people who insisted on getting a form of symbolic constants more substantial than Cpp's parameterless macros." (section 11.7, "Cpp" refers to the C preprocessor, the rest of the section chronicles the decision to make each `enum` a separate type in C++ instead of all of them being `int`s as they originally were in C and early versions of C++).

`enum`s are largely meant as a way of replacing `#define`s in earlier versions of C.

```
// based on UNIX file permissions
#define EXECUTE 1
#define WRITE 2
#define READ 4
```

vs.

```
const int EXECUTE = 1;
const int WRITE = 2;
const int READ = 4;
```

vs.

```
enum File_perms {
    EXECUTE = 1;
    WRITE = 2;
    READ = 4;
};
```

[Which to use is largely a matter of personal taste](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#in-class).  An `enum` does provide a form of documentation about what kind of values a variable should hold:

```
int permissions = 4; // Was that file permissions, database permissions, or something else?
File_perms perms = 4;
```

This is especially helpful in function signatures:

```
int fiddle_bits(int, int); // I can never remember if I pass the file permissions as the first or second parameter ...
File_perms fiddle_bits2(File_perms, int);
```

`enum`s are allowed in `switch` statement `case` labels (as are `#define`s and `const int`s):

```
switch (perm) {
    case READ:
        ...
    break;
    ...
}
```

However, note that it *is* possible to assign numbers to `enum`s that don't have a labeled value (C++0x adds an `enum class` that doesn't allow this):

```
File_perms perm = 7; // a.k.a., File_perms perm = EXECUTE | READ | WRITE;
```

If you ever see an `enum` with explicit values that are powers of 2, you can almost guarantee that it will be used this way.

Comment: enums were "not added to C++", they are a (quite dangerous) legacy from C. Plain 'C' enums are of limited use in C++, therefore the latest C++ specification draft (finally!) added type safe 'enum struct' and 'enum class' constructs.

Comment: @paul_71: the Wikipedia article on enums agree with you, "C++ has enumeration types that are directly inherited from C's", but I'm not sure. I just checked my 1978 copy of "The C Programming Language" and at that time C didn't have enums, but in C89 they were there. And C++ started circa 1980. Funny "anacronism" disucssed in 1978 in TCPL: original C allowed declarations w/init like "int x 666;" but this was changed to "int x = 666;" because "int x (42+1);" resembled a function decl "enough to confuse compilers"; and it's STILL the "most vexing parse" in C++... :-)

Comment: Hm, I don' have a c-standard at hand, so I trust you fully if you already looked it up. It's also true that C++ started around 1980, but the first C++ standard specification stems from 1998 where 100% compatibility with C (of that time) was guaranteed. In fact, it still is, since those unutterably unsafe 'enums' are not going to disappear...as are not the reasons for the 'vexing parses'...

Comment: You guys are right.  I had based my comments on an incorrect memory from "The Design and Evolution of C++."  But that book says "I had no need for enumerations in the styles of programming I wished to support and no particular wish to meddle in the affairs of enumerations, so C++ adopted C's rule unchanged."  I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

For example, consider this enumeration:

```
enum ip_packet_type {
    ip = 0,
    icmp = 1,
    igmp = 2,
    tcp = 6,
    udp = 17,
    // many others
};
```

This represents the IP protocol number in IP packets. Inside a packet, the protocol number is identified by a *number* rather than a *name* (8 bits at byte offset 9). This enumeration lets the program source refer to names like `icmp` and `tcp` rather than numbers. The number must be used inside the IP packet itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you use an `enum` the values (such as `black`, `green`, etc.) are symbolic names that are represented internally as integers.

If you used a string array, then every time you wanted to use one of those values you’d need to copy the string, do a string compare, etc.

In addition, the `enum` can *only* contain the pre-defined values, which is desirable most of the time. If you represented the same thing as string there’s no such guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

An enumerator (like `black` in your example) is represented by an integer; comparing integers is *fast*.  Comparing strings is not fast.

In addition, you get type safety.  If you used strings like `"black"` and `"blue"`, there's no guarantee that someone doesn't pass you `"hot dog"` when you expect a color.  If you take a `color_t`, you are guaranteed to get a valid color (unless someone has gone and done something wrong).

Answer (score 1):

1) Enum vs Integers: Enums are easier to read and hence code is more maintenable.

2) Enum vs Strings: Enums are much more efficient (alsmo as effecient as integers).

Added advantage: Enums are automatically restricted to the range of values you predefine. This also means that they are useful only when the range of values is small.